# Is the performance of join two one-to-one tables on a single-node database the same as a pure select on an equivalent denormalized table?

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, relational-database

There are two big (millions of records) *one-to-one* tables:

- `course`
- `prerequisite` with a *foreign key* reference to the `course` table

in single-node relational *MySQL* database. A `join` is needed to list the full description of all the courses.

An alternative is to have only one single table to contain both the `course` and `prerequisite` data in the same database.

**Question: is the performance of the `join` query still slower than that of a simple select query without `join` on the single *denormalized* table albeit the fact that they are on the same single-node *MYSQL* database?**

Comment: What were the results of the tests you must have done to investigate?

Comment: I dont know yet, so am here asking

Comment: Can't a course have more than one prerequisite?

Answer (score 2):

It's true that denormalization is often done to shorten the work to look up one record with its associated details. This usually means the query responds in less time.

But denormalization improves one query at the expense of other queries against the same data. Making one query faster will often make other queries slower. For example, what if you want to query the set of courses that have a given prerequisite?

It's also a risk when you use denormalization that you create data anomalies. For example, if you change a course name, you would also need to update all the places where it is named as a prerequisite. If you forget one, then you'll have a weird scenario where the obsolete name for a course is still used in some places.

How will you know you found them all? How much work in the form of extra queries will you have to do to double-check that you have no anomalies? Do those types of extra queries count toward making your database slower on average?

The purpose of normalizing a database is not performance. It's avoiding data anomalies, which reduces your work in other ways.

Comment: The reason why I ask such question is: I have been woring in 3 software system product companies, among which one is even a pretty big software product house with more than 1000 employees globally. But the databases in all these 3 companies have table containing even hundreds of fields, which is in my humble opinion needed to be normalized even if the result of normalization does not reduce data redundancy, but I am not sure if my point of view is proper or not

Comment: I don't know why they did that. It could be that they measured the performance, and for their use case, it was an advantage to denormalize. Or it could be that it's not denormalized at all, but it's an entity that happens to have hundreds of distinct single-valued attributes (I know this is not likely). You should ask the person who designed it if they had a good reason, before you assume that it needs to be changed.

Comment: If I want to query the set of courses that have a given prerequisite in case of denormalized one table, I just need to have an index on the prerequisite field, then query performance would be fast, isn't it? In the tittle I mentioned the relationship between course and prerequisite is one-to-one

Comment: If the prerequisite is a single-valued attribute of the course, then yes it can be an attribute column, and an index can help.

Comment: Its to good mention one to one design when there is an involvement on table locking , for eg. in a one-to-one relationship, if the frequently changing columns are in a separate table, the impact of locking may be reduced. Changes to one table might not necessarily affect the other if the relationship is properly managed.